# How can I disable the volume warning if you raise the volume too much?

Tags: nexus-4, volume

I recently got a Nexus 4, and I've got a question regarding the volume warning that pops up if you raise the volume too much. Is it possible to disable or remove this warning? I want to be able to raise the volume with the phone in my pocket (with the volume buttons) without having to pick up the phone. I listen to podcasts with low or bad audio and need to raise it above the warning level.

Comment: I only seem to get the warning the first time I raise the volume after a reboot.

Comment: It's possible using Xposed Framework if you have a rooted phone. Detailed instructions here: http://gs4.wonderhowto.com/how-to/get-rid-annoying-high-volume-alert-when-using-headphones-your-samsung-galaxy-s4-0148825/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40365) (or feature) in Android 4.2, and there's probably no fix for now.

**UPDATE 2013-12-10:** According to [Marius Hofert](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44737/marius-hofert), it is still an issue in 4.4.

Comment: Okay, to bad :/

Comment: It's (still!) an issue in Android 4.4 (kitkat). People have reported that it can be fixed with a custom rom, but I believe Google should provide a switch to turn it off.

Answer (score 3):

Android source code explains it perfectly in AudioService.java
For any experienced Android hacker, It's quite easy to patch it out though.

```
//==========================================================================================
 // Safe media volume management.
 // MUSIC stream volume level is limited when headphones are connected according to safety
 // regulation. When the user attempts to raise the volume above the limit, a warning is
 // displayed and the user has to acknowlegde before the volume is actually changed.
 // The volume index corresponding to the limit is stored in config_safe_media_volume_index
 // property. Platforms with a different limit must set this property accordingly in their
 // overlay.
 //==========================================================================================

 // mSafeMediaVolumeState indicates whether the media volume is limited over headphones.
 // It is SAFE_MEDIA_VOLUME_NOT_CONFIGURED at boot time until a network service is connected
 // or the configure time is elapsed. It is then set to SAFE_MEDIA_VOLUME_ACTIVE or
 // SAFE_MEDIA_VOLUME_DISABLED according to country option. If not SAFE_MEDIA_VOLUME_DISABLED, it
 // can be set to SAFE_MEDIA_VOLUME_INACTIVE by calling AudioService.disableSafeMediaVolume()
 // (when user opts out).
```

Comment: How about an inexperienced "hacker" who happens to be a developer? What is the best option? Custom ROMS, patching the stock version, etc. I would like to ensure I still received OTA updates for the Nexus 4.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an implementation of the European Union regulations to limit the volume to 85db unless the user confirms they want to raise the volume higher ([BBC news article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/8410302.stm)).

I guess this does not apply in the US and other regions?

It's possible that some custom ROMs may let you disable this feature.