# Can I disable the volume warning if I raise the volume too much?

Tags: volume-control, volume

Occasionally when I raise the volume on my HTC-one, I get a warning message which stops me until I click 'Ok'. It's more of an annoyance than anything else. Can I disable it? I can't seem to find an option for it in the settings.

This question has already been asked [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39583/how-can-i-disable-the-volume-warning-if-you-raise-the-volume-too-much), but it was over a year ago. 
There was no solution then, I'm wondering does anyone know if there is a solution now?

Comment: This isn't a forum, so we don't ask duplicate questions just to seek new answers for the same question. You can add a bounty to draw more attention to a question, even when it isn't your question: one of the preset bounty reasons is "the existing answers are out of date". I think, though, that you'll find the answers haven't changed.

Comment: It's not a possible duplicate, it IS a duplicate. Read the question.

Comment: If you check the [accepted answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39586/16575), it was updated for Kitkat (4.4) half a year ago: status unchanged.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, that answer was the reason I asked this question in the first place. 'it is still an issue in 4.4.' I was just hoping someone had figured something out since then.